# Variable to replace %s for sql is not getting honored

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.8

I have a table with single empty row inserted. Later I want to update column with some value into the row. I am trying to compose a function which will work for all the columns as shown

```
def update_column(field, value):
    print(field, value)
    sql = '''UPDATE `table name` SET %s = %s WHERE `ID` = 1'''
    params = (field,value)
    execute_sql(sql, params)
```

upon execution update_column('fieldName', 10), getting following error. Any help is appreciated.

> Failed to execute command UPDATE TABLE2 SET %s = %s WHERE `ID` = 1 in
> database due to: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near ''TEST' = 10 WHERE `ID` = 1' at line 1

Not sure if %s for the field name is the acceptable use case or not. If anyone familiar with such cases, please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: What host language is this? Python? Tag it, it seems more important here. I don't know for your host language, but in any I know you cannot use parameters for object identifiers. You need to use string concatenation or interpolation (if available) for them. But be sure to properly sanitize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use query parameters for column names (or table names, sql keywords, expressions, lists, etc.).

A query parameter is filled in as if it were a quoted string, after escaping any literal quote characters in that string.* That's why it ends up as `'TEST' = 10` and not `TEST = 10`.

For column names, you have to do that yourself, *without* the parameter treatment.

It's up to you to make sure this is safe. If you use the back-ticks, then the only thing you have to do is make sure your `field` variable does not contain literal back-tick characters.

```
field.replace('`', '')
sql = '''UPDATE `table name` SET `{field}` = %s WHERE `ID` = 1'''.format(field=field)
```

---

* This is true for Python, which interpolates parameter values into the string before it submits the SQL query to the server. That's not a real query parameter; a real parameter leaves the placeholder until after the query is parsed. Python doesn't support that kind of parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
def update_column(field, value):
    print(field, value)
    sql = f'''UPDATE `table name` SET {field} = {value} WHERE `ID` = 1'''
```

and then execute the query?
And don't forget to add quotation marks if the value was a string
like:

```
sql = f'''UPDATE `table name` SET {filed} = '{value}' WHERE `ID` = 1'''
```

Comment: This is an SQL injection vulnerability. You can format `value` into the query as an f-string, but if the content of `value` has special characters, those characters are not escaped. You should use the SQL parameters method, which will escape special characters.